# Create a month (columns) week (rows) calendar year data model

Tags: c#, linq

I need to create the data model to build the following HTML:

[image]

I was thinking in having for columns:

```
Dictionary<string,int> columns = new Dictionary<string,int>();
```

So I will have something like this:

```
columns.Add(0,""); // this is the day week column
columns.Add(9,"Sep");
columns.Add(10,"Oct");
columns.Add(11,"Nov");
columns.Add(12,"Dec");
columns.Add(1,"Jan");
// and so on....
```

Then my row model should be something like this:

```
public class CalendarMonthDataModel
{
   public int Month {get;set;}
   public byte Index {get;set;} // this is the vertical position index to place the Day value
   public byte Day {get;set;} // this is the Day (1,2,3, etc.)
}
```

So with that model, if I want to fill September data I would do this:

```
var dataMonth = new CalendarMonthDataModel();
dataMonth.Month = 9; // september
dataMonth.Index = 6; // Day 1 starts in the position 6 (start from 0)
dataMonth.Class = "N"; // the css class (N = normal, D = disabled)
dataMonth.Day = 1;
```

And so on...

My questions are:

> 1. Is this the best way to generate the calendar data model or there is another way?
> 2. How can I know the total of rows depending on the year and months that I will show?

I hope someone can guide me on a good solution to solve this puzzle :).

Comment: If you look carefully at your visualization, I think you'll see that you need to be using a list of lists (or a dictionary of lists, lol). So a `Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, in>>>` (visualize as {"SEPT", {{"MON", 1}, {"TUES", 2}...}), or something like that. Once you fill this dictionary of lists out, it's just a matter of unspooling it into a datatable (or more preferably, directly binding the dictionary of lists to the output, thought that's going to be less than trivial in ASP.NET/HTML).

Comment: Any clue on how to dynamically fill this list depending on the year and months to show?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution:

In case someone need to do something like this:

```
var model = new List<EmployeeHolidayPeriodCalendarModel>();

            var actualDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 1);

            // loop 12 months
            for (int index = 1; index <= 12; index++)
            {
                var date = new DateTime(actualDate.Year, actualDate.Month, 1);
                var monthInfo = new EmployeeHolidayPeriodCalendarModel();
                monthInfo.Month = (byte)date.Month;
                monthInfo.Year = date.Year;
                monthInfo.WeekDayStart = Convert.ToByte(date.DayOfWeek); // 0 = Sunday....
                monthInfo.DaysInMonth = Convert.ToByte(DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month));
                monthInfo.MonthName = date.ToString("MMM");

                // increment date by adding months
                actualDate= actualDate.AddMonths(1);

                model.Add(monthInfo);
            }
            // the month where weekdaystart is first
            byte firstWeekDay = model.Min(m => m.WeekDayStart);
            byte lastWeekDay = model.Max(m => m.WeekDayStart);
            decimal maxDaysInMonth = model.Max(m => m.DaysInMonth);

            // calculate total model rows
            byte totalRows = Convert.ToByte((lastWeekDay - firstWeekDay)+maxDaysInMonth - 1);

            // fill each month data
            foreach (var month in model)
            {
                month.Items = new List<PeriodCalendarRowModel>();

                byte rowIndex = Convert.ToByte(month.WeekDayStart-firstWeekDay);
                int negRowIndex = Convert.ToInt16(rowIndex * -1);


                for (byte dayRow = 1; dayRow <= totalRows; dayRow++)
                {
                    var day = dayRow + negRowIndex;
                    if (day < 1 || day > month.DaysInMonth)
                    {
                        // add empty data
                        var newDay = new PeriodCalendarRowModel();
                        newDay.Day = 0;
                        newDay.Month = month.Month;
                        newDay.RowIndex = dayRow;

                        month.Items.Add(newDay);
                    }

                    if (day >= 1 && day <= month.DaysInMonth)
                    {
                        // add normal data
                        var newDay = new PeriodCalendarRowModel();
                        newDay.Day = (byte)day;
                        newDay.Month = month.Month;
                        newDay.RowIndex = dayRow;

                        month.Items.Add(newDay);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I am also stucked in creating this type calendar.Can you explain me how you solved it?